# Bootbox alert not popping up in a $.post(url, data).done() code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, bootbox

I have the following code that submits a form from a jsp page.

The call to `mywebpage.jsp` returns a SOAP response with all the parameters that are used in the alerts.

I know that the code executes correctly because I can see the `console.log()` out put. The `bootbox.alerts` don't pop up. 
I've tried using `callback()` on the `bootbox.alerts` and `bootbox.confirm` and swapping them for normal `window.alert`. I still get the same results.

```
    $('form.myForm').submit(function (event) {
        var url = "mywebpage.jsp";
        var data = { param1: "value1", param2: "value2", param3: "value3"};
        $.post(url, data)
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var IErrCode = $(data).find("IErrCode").text();
            if (IErrCode==0)
            {
                console.log("Validate Sign IErrCode==0");
                bootbox.alert('Saved.<br>' + $(data).find("SOutMsg").text());
            } else {
                console.log("Validate Sign IErrCode!=0");
                bootbox.alert($(data).find("SErrDesc").text() + $(data).find("IErrCode").text());
            }
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown +"(" + textStatus + ")");
            bootbox.alert( errorThrown +"(" + textStatus + ")");
        });
        return true;
    });
```

Is there a way that I can implement this so that the user can see the popups?

**UPDATE**

I have changed the `$.post(url,data)` to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    async:false
})
```

I understand that this is bad practice but it is the only way that I can get it to work.
I can now see the `Bootbox.alerts` but they close too quickly to be able to read them. I have tried changing them to `Bootbox.confirms` but they still close too quickly.

I there another way to force them to stay open until the user accepts them?

Comment: did you add all required libraries ? also does your browser console shows any error ?

Comment: @Swati I'm sure that I do have all the required libraries. the popups work on other pages. I get warnings about `[Violation] Avoid using document.write().` and `[Violation] Parser was blocked due to document.write(<script>)` but no errors.

Comment: This has been covered in the docs and in a few related questions - you need to either cancel the form submission (`event.preventDefault()`) or use `return false` at the end of your script. Bootbox just makes Bootstrap modals, which are just positioned divs - they don't block your code like native dialogs would.

Comment: @TiesonT. I've tried adding `event.preventDefault()` and `return false`. When I do I get the following error back from the SOAP service `Error on Insert(PROOF_OF_DLVR) - ORA-00984: column not allowed here`

Comment: That doesn't sound like anything to do with your client-side code (or, at least, the Bootbox usage). That error implies an error in your SQL statement. For starters, though, assuming your form works when posted normally, you should probably be using this to create your data object: `var data = $(this).serialize();`, where `$(this)` is the object which `$('form.myForm')` selected. Probably also want to call your response object something other than `data`, given that variable already exists.